# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component, in SceneView (created by Pager)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I got following error than I tried to find out what cause it but all-over internet is just different answers for similar issues but not specifically for my. I tried to updating packages which I found not updated `npm outdated`. Warning come up during navigation update. Anyone came across similar issue?

```
"react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
"expo": "^38.0.0",
```

```
 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method, 
    in SceneView (created by Pager)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:233)
    in AnimatedComponent(Component) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Pager)
    in Pager (created by TabView)
    in RCTView (created by TabView)
    in TabView (created by MaterialTabView)
    in MaterialTabView (created by NavigationView)
    in NavigationView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:889)
    in RCTView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:144)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:194)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:144)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:194)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at src/index.native.js:101)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at src/index.native.js:132)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:144)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:194)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (created by withOrientation)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by KeyboardAwareNavigator)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (created by ResourceSavingScene)
    in RCTView (created by ResourceSavingScene)
    in ResourceSavingScene (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (at src/index.native.js:132)
    in ScreenContainer (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:233)
    in AnimatedComponent(Component) (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:233)
    in AnimatedComponent(Component) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Drawer)
    in Drawer (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
    in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (at RootNavigation.tsx:103)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually indicates, that a state update is triggered too late, when the component already has been unmounted. In your case most likely after navigating.

It's not really possible to pinpoint the problem without knowing the code. I assume you have somewhere a timeout or async operation. E.g. an event listener that updates state which can be triggered even after the component has been unmounted.
The solution here is to unsubscribe any event listeners and stream-like operations in your componentWillUnmount lifecycle. Or if you use functional components as a return function in your effect.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('resize', myFunc);
  return () => document.removeEventListener('resize', myFunc);
}, [...]);
```

The same goes for timeouts, you can store the active timeout in a ref object and clear it in your unmount lifecycle.

Comment: this seems to me very interesting. I will try out this solution and will come back to you. Thank you

Comment: nice I got success with this answer. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Can you mark the answer as the correct answer? So that it's clear that the question has been answered.